# Push notification with Ad Hoc and Store distributions

Tags: ios, push-notification, adhoc

Is there any reason to prevent enterprise ad hoc builds of an app from contacting Apple's push notification service if you've got a Store version of the same app (built with the same distribution certificate) running at the same time?

I know from experience how important it is to keep development apps on the sandbox APN service, but recently we've been using ad hoc enterprise distributions for internal testing and we do not want to mix ad hoc/store device IDs if it's going to have the same effect. I believe that there is no problem allowing ad hoc versions and store versions to mix, but I can't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why ad hoc builds contacting production APNs would be a problem. It was Apple's decision that ad hoc builds use the production gateway rather than a separate one. Developers are not given a choice here.

Comment: I agree that it sounds reasonable. But I'd really prefer not to try this without knowing the answer first.

Comment: I've been testing with production gateway with adhoc builds, because there is no other way to do it. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Well thank you for being a test subject for me!! Have you had any issues with pushes to your store-based app after doing pushes to you ad-hocs? As for alternatives, for me I would create a different bundle identifier for the ad-hoc/development version, but it's a pest to change this for every update submission.